# Crontab and Python prog not running completely

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to get a Python script to run hourly using crontab however I cannot seem to get it to work.

The Python program runs fine and completes if I manually run it from terminal.

```
$ python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py
```

My crontab is setup like so:

```
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py

0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py

0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/SimpleCronTest.py
```

Let me clarify though, I followed suggestions [on this similar post.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/cant-run-python-script-from-cron) I tried the simple test script that creates an output file and that worked. However under the same crontab with the same settings, my program doesn't complete.

The interesting point is that using TOP when the script is due to start, the Python window briefly pops up before disappearing again. So I assume cron is at least sort of working.

I have added the:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

Python line to the top of the Base_Prog.py file. 
My Python program is an API scraper that finds its inputs from one file and writes the results to another, all files in the project directory have full write permissions using chmod 777.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

*UPDATE*

The output log for both the simple test and my programme in the syslog is:

```
Apr  2 14:29:01 raspberrypi CRON[1455]: (pi) CMD (python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py)
Apr  2 14:29:01 raspberrypi CRON[1456]: (pi) CMD (python /home/pi/Documents/CronTest.py)
```

Comment: What sort of work your script doing?

Comment: Put the code of your script here

Answer (score 0):

I think full solution is:

First add a SHEBANG line on top of your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make your script executable with chmod +x

If your script work with stdout or if you need to know what's wrong:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py >> tmp.log
```

And just to clarify:

```
0 * * * * -means the cron will run always when the minutes are 0 (hourly)
```

Comment: I have tested with and without the SHEBANG line. The program itself and all files in the directory have all the necessary permissions from chmod 777, read write and executable. I added the >> tmp.log but I cannot find any output in the directory after its supposed to have run. Note, I am changing the time to be a couple of minutes in the future from when I'm testing, I'm not waiting an hour each time if thats what you mean by the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the output of the *cron* execution for any clues, not just running it from terminal.  Perhaps there are some permission/ownership errors or something along those lines.  From the cron execution, you can send output to a file to view:

```
 0 * * * * python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py 1> /dev/null 2> /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.err
```

and you can view `/home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.err` after for clues.  Or you can also have it emailed to you:

```
0 * * * * python /home/pi/Documents/Project/Base_Prog.py 1> /dev/null 2>&1 | mail -s "Base Program Output" you@company.com
```